# Search Filter with React Native on FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to search through a flatlist based on a search bar text. The problem I am running into is that when the user mistypes...say they wanted to type "burger" but typed "burget" by mistake then it returns nothing as it should. When the user deletes the "t" then it should re-render the flatlist again with the last text matching the "burge" part.

note: using react-native-elements search bar which allows me to call the text with just e or event.

What I have so far in the Main.js file:

```
searchText = (e) => {
    let text = e.toLowerCase();
    let trucks = this.state.data;

    // search by food truck name
    let filteredName = trucks.filter((truck) => {
      return truck.name.toLowerCase().match(text); 
    });

    // if no match and text is empty
    if(!text || text === '') {
      console.log('change state');
        this.setState({
          data: initial
        });
      }
    // if no name matches to text output
    else if(!Array.isArray(filteredName) && !filteredName.length) {
      console.log("not name");
      this.setState({
        data: [],
      });
    }
    // if name matches then display
    else if(Array.isArray(filteredName)) {
      console.log('Name');
      this.setState({
        data: filteredName,
      });
    }
   };

<View style={styles.container}>
  <SearchBar
    round
    lightTheme
    containerStyle={styles.search}
    ref="search"
    textInputRef="searchText"
    onChangeText={this.searchText.bind(this)}
    placeholder='Search by Truck Name...'
   />
   <TruckList getTruck={(truck) => this.setTruck(truck)} truckScreen={this.truckScreen} data={this.state.data}/>
</View>
```

then the TruckList.JS:

```
export default class TruckList extends Component {
    // rendering truck screen
    renderTruckScreen = (item) => {
        this.props.truckScreen();
        this.props.getTruck(item);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <List style={styles.list}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <ListItem
                            roundAvatar
                            avatar={{uri: item.pic1}}
                            avatarStyle={styles.avatar}
                            title={item.name}
                            titleStyle={styles.title}
                            subtitle={
                                <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
                                    <Text style={styles.subtitleFood}>{item.food}</Text>
                                    <View style={styles.subtitleInfo}>
                                        <Icon 
                                            name="favorite"
                                            size={20}
                                            color={"#f44336"}
                                            style={styles.subtitleFavorite}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={styles.subtitleFavoriteText}>{item.favorited} favorited</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            }
                            onPress={() => this.renderTruckScreen(item)}
                        />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.uid}
                    ListFooterComponent={this.footer}
                />
            </List>
        )
      }
    }
```

I have tried a few other ways to no avail. Also the only solutions I have seen working for React Native are with ListView which will be depreciated in time. So I am trying to do this with the new FlatList Component.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's the problem? Is it re-render not happening when user modifies the search text?

Comment: @Umesh the problem is that when the user mistypes the data is set to `[]` and then when they delete the mistype the data should be reset back to the last state of the search...just haven't figured out how that might work. Possibly setting previous state then calling it somehow?

Comment: When user mistypes, your result is empty [ ] but when user corrects it, will it not fetch the results again ? I guess onChange, you get the results every time.

Comment: It should fetch the results again, however, it does not. The mistype sets the data to `[]` but then when you delete the mistype the data is still `[]`. When I console log during the typing what happens is after deleting the mistype it goes back to the `else if(Array.isArray(filteredName))` however, there is no data for is to reset state to or something like that

Comment: May be you need to tweak your conditional order. My opinion is to search and store the results on every text search change, rather than relying on previous result set.

Comment: @Umesh well, I guess your method is better than trying to handle a mistype. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. I hope that I was able to help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I came across this same issue today when trying to implement a filter / search function on the new FlatList component. This is how I managed to solve it:

By creating another item in the state of the parent component called noData, you can set that to true when there are no results that match your search and then render your FlatList conditionally.

My implementation is slightly different to yours, but if I had to adjust your code it would look something like this:

Searchtext function:

```
searchText = (e) => {
    let text = e.toLowerCase()
    let trucks = this.state.data
    let filteredName = trucks.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().match(text)
    })
    if (!text || text === '') {
      this.setState({
        data: initial
      })
    } else if (!Array.isArray(filteredName) && !filteredName.length) {
      // set no data flag to true so as to render flatlist conditionally
      this.setState({
        noData: true
      })
    } else if (Array.isArray(filteredName)) {
      this.setState({
        noData: false,
        data: filteredName
      })
    }
  }
```

Then pass the noData bool to your TruckList component:

```
<TruckList getTruck={(truck) => this.setTruck(truck)} 
truckScreen={this.truckScreen} data={this.state.data} noData={this.state.noData}/>
```

Then render your FlatList in the TruckList component only if there are results:

```
<List style={styles.list}>
{this.props.noData ? <Text>NoData</Text> : <FlatList {...} />}         
</List>
```

That should then take care of handling user typing errors - as it will re-render the flatlist as soon as there are no results, and will remember the previous search state when you remove the typing error..

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Do you guys have a github link for this solution ?

Comment: not working for me  , when i am doing console of trucks.filter((item) => {console.log(item) }   it is giving "message: "item is not defined""

Comment: in item.name.toLowerCase() it is giving error  as well

Comment: If you console log the data that you are filtering do you get any data in there?

Comment: Is passing `this.props.noData` really required? Wouldn't it be cleaner just to check `if(this.props.data)`

Answer (score 21):

For a useful in-memory search you should keep initial data seperately.

I have more simple solution for this.

This solution for in-memory search on FlatList's data and uses it String.prototype​.includes() method to search substring.

You can find full source code of this component in this gist;
https://gist.github.com/metehansenol/46d065b132dd8916159910d5e9586058

My initial state;

```
this.state = {
  searchText: "",
  data: [],
  filteredData: []
};
```

My SearchBar component (it comes from react-native-elements package);

```
<SearchBar
  round={true}
  lightTheme={true}
  placeholder="Search..."
  autoCapitalize='none'
  autoCorrect={false}
  onChangeText={this.search}
  value={this.state.searchText}
/>
```

My search method;

```
search = (searchText) => {
  this.setState({searchText: searchText});

  let filteredData = this.state.data.filter(function (item) {
    return item.description.includes(searchText);
  });

  this.setState({filteredData: filteredData});
};
```

And last my FlatList's DataSource expression;

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.filteredData && this.state.filteredData.length > 0 ? this.state.filteredData : this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => `item-${item.id}`}
  renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem
    id={item.id}
    code={item.code}
    description={item.description}
  />}
/>
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** 
[This blog](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699) can help you better understand the searching in a FlatList.

**FYI:**
If you have huge online data then you can also use [algolia](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/Getting_started_React_native.html).

I adjusted the above code for me in order to make it work properly. The reason is that when user removes the last wrong character, code search this new string from a previous search list (state) which does not contain all objects, although it had to search from a full list available. So, I have two list now. One contains full list of objects and second contains only rendered list of objects which is changing upon search.

```
handleSearchInput(e){
    let text = e.toLowerCase()
    let fullList = this.state.fullListData;
    let filteredList = fullList.filter((item) => { // search from a full list, and not from a previous search results list
      if(item.guest.fullname.toLowerCase().match(text))
        return item;
    })
    if (!text || text === '') {
      this.setState({
        renderedListData: fullList,
        noData:false,
      })
    } else if (!filteredList.length) {
     // set no data flag to true so as to render flatlist conditionally
       this.setState({
         noData: true
       })
    }
    else if (Array.isArray(filteredList)) {
      this.setState({
        noData: false,
        renderedListData: filteredList
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

## Make Search Bar Filter for List View Data in React Native

#### For Real-Time Searching in List View using Search Bar Filter

- We will load the list from the network call and then show it to the user.
- The user can search the data by entering the text in TextInput.
- After inserting the text SearchFilterFunction will be called We will
  compare the list data with the inserted data and will make a new Data
  source.
- We will update the data source attached to the ListView.
- It will re-render the list and the user will be able to see the
  filtered data.

```js
//This is an example code to Add Search Bar Filter on Listview//
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
 
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.
 
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //setting default state
    this.state = { isLoading: true, text: '' };
    this.arrayholder = [];
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson
          },
          function() {
            this.arrayholder = responseJson;
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  SearchFilterFunction(text) {
    //passing the inserted text in textinput
    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function(item) {
      //applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
      const itemData = item.title ? item.title.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      //setting the filtered newData on datasource
      //After setting the data it will automatically re-render the view
      dataSource: newData,
      text: text,
    });
  }
  ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
    //Item sparator view
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.3,
          width: '90%',
          backgroundColor: '#080808',
        }}
      />
    );
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      //Loading View while data is loading
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      //ListView to show with textinput used as search bar
      <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
          value={this.state.text}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Search Here"
        />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
          )}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40,
    padding: 16,
  },
  textStyle: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  textInputStyle: {
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    borderColor: '#009688',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
});
```

[Click Hear for more idea](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-search-bar-filter-on-listview/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

You need to have a backup of your data

```
this.state = {
    data: [],
    backup: []
}
```

on search method

```
search = txt => {
    let text = txt.toLowerCase()
    let tracks = this.state.backup
    let filterTracks = tracks.filter(item => {
    if(item.name.toLowerCase().match(text)) {
      return item
    }
  })
  this.setState({ data: filterTracks })
}
```

Explanation: when calling setState on your data it will changed to current state and cannot be changed again.

So backup data will handle to filter your data.

Answer (score 3):

ref - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  data: [],
  value: ""
};

this.arrayholder = [];
}
```

Next fetching data :-

```
_fetchdata = async () => {
const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api?results=10");
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: json.results });

this.arrayholder = json.results;
};
```

Next define searchFilterFunction :-

```
searchFilterFunction = text => {
this.setState({
  value: text
});


const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
  const itemData = item.email.toLowerCase();

  const textData = text.toLowerCase();

  return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
});

this.setState({ data: newData });
};
```

rendering searchView:-

```
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
    />
```

Don't forget to  import TextInput from "react-native";

Answer (score 1):

You can Search your data by following these steps :

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(text) => searchData(text)} value={input} />
```

```
***Please Note *searchData is my function whom I passing a text prop***
```

```
const searchData = (text) => {
    const newData = restaurantsData.filter((item) => {
        return item.title.search(text) > -1;
    });
    setRestaurantsData(newData);
    setInput(text);
};
```

***Note RestaurantsData is my data array***

Answer (score 0):

**FYI** : `data` is the `subtext` to be searched, this is a basic search implemented as the data to be searched is looked into every list item of an array which is a copy of the actual `array/array` of `objects` and finally its state is set whether match found or not between `0` to (`actualArray.length-1`) and the temporary `arrayData` is rendered if there is at least one match else `actualArray` is rendered

```js
implementSearch(data) {
    temp = [];
    var count = 0;
    var searchData = data.toUpperCase();
    var arr = this.state.personDetail;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var actualData = arr[i].name.toUpperCase();
      if (actualData.includes(searchData)) {
        temp.push(arr[i]);
        count++;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      tempArray: temp,
      matches: count,
      searchValue: data
    });
  }
```

**Hope** this helps

Answer (score 0):

> My search method; from @metehan-senol

```
search = (searchText) => {
 this.setState({searchText: searchText});

 let filteredData = this.state.data.filter(function (item) {
   return item.description.includes(searchText);
 });

 this.setState({filteredData: filteredData});
};
```

the search method of could be simplify and Eslint proof like so

```
search = (searchText) => {
  const searched = searchText.toLowerCase();
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    searchText: searched,
    filteredData: prevState.data.filter(item =>
      item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searched)
    ),
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do filter by applying

```
let filterData= data.filter((item) => {
  return item.name.toLowerCase().match(text)
})
if (!text || text === '') {
  this.setState({
    datasource: initial
  })
} else if (!Array.isArray(filterData) && !filterData.length) {
  // set no data flag to true so as to render flatlist conditionally
  this.setState({
    noData: true
  })
} else if (Array.isArray(filterData)) {
  this.setState({
    noData: false,`enter code here`
    dataSource: filterData
  })`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution in terms of performance, but if you do not have a large amount of data, then feel free to use this function:

```
  searchFilter () {
    return this.props.data.filter((item) => {
       const regex = new RegExp(this.state.searchInput, "gi")
       return item.label.match(regex);
    })
  }
```

And then in your FlatList component:

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.searchFilter()}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

const SearchUser = (e) =>{
console.log(e)
const setProject = Project.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.toLowerCase()) )
console.log(setProject)
setfetch(setProject)
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).