# How to make specific item in flatlist appears first one to appear react native?

Tags: arrays, react-native

How I can make specific item in flatlist be the first one to appear like number 3 instead of number 1 and after that append the first and second items to the end of new array.

How I can also scroll to the beginning of the new array when I reach the end?

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Fourth Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Fifth Item',
  },
];
****
const renderItem=({ item,index }) => {
  <ListItem>
  <View>
  <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  </View>
  </ListItem>
}
```

The desired output:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Fourth Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Fifth Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
];
```

```
 <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
 />
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Be clear your question can help you accordingly. What you actually want your result be?

Comment: const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'Fourth Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'fifth Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'first Item',
  },
  {
    title: 'second Item',
  },
];

Comment: and when the user reach second item he return back to third item

Comment: If you want to update flatlist data on search, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666762/search-filter-with-react-native-on-flatlist