# Is there any alternative for "Asyncselect" of "React" in "react-native"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]I am new to React-native and stuck in one issue as I am still exploring options in it. My current issue is, I need to display a searchable drop down where it will display top five items and its going to come from an api and with a search field on the top. When user types the data in search field, the drop down will start searching it by calling a async api and get the data and display in same drop down. Is it possible in react-native? In react, it can be done using "react-select/async" package. Below is the react code:
React:

```
async getOptions(inputValue, callback) {
    
    if (!inputValue) {
      return callback([]);
    }
    const response = await fetch(
      `${this.state... }?search=${inputValue}&limit=${
        this.state...
      }`
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    return callback(json.results);
  }

<AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        value={selectedValue}
        getOptionLabel={e => e.title}
        getOptionValue={e => e.id}
        loadOptions={getOptions}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
```

There is a loadOptions param which is a callback function and it returns the data by calling async function.

Can we do the same in react-native or which alternative we can use.?

I am new to react-native any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you want a dropdown with search box inside this ?

Comment: @Jals I have attached a screen shot. Yes, I need something like in mentioned image. The above thing is implemented using "react-select/async" in react. it loads the data using async method call and the time you try to type something in search bar, then it again call api and get the data from server and display in drop down. I guess it called as autocomplete. thanks in advance

Comment: Havea look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45675012/12082336

Comment: @DarshanJain This does not go with my requirement as I need a drop down with searchable bar in it. The answer mentioned by, Jals, is some what , what i need. But i have server side search involved means if i type somethin in search bar inside drop down, it should trigger an api call to check for data searched. Same thing can be done in React using "AsyncSelect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer `react-native-searchable-dropdown` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown) or `react-native-dropdown-searchable` [here](https://github.com/KianooshSoleimani/react-native-searchableDropDown)

Comment: let me have a look. I will get back to you, Thanks :) for the reply

Comment: Hi Jals, this solution works great. But one problem is after selecting the option from SearchableDropdown, it does not change the text textinput value. Its a known bug in that. But i will still accept this answer as it somewhat solving problem. Thanks